# Congruence with power

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

We were given a congruence 
$$
X=2^{2012} \mod{6}
$$
And we asked our professor what's the solution and she replied with
$$
X=2^{2012} \mod{2}
$$
$$
X=0^{2012} \mod{2}
$$
$$
X=0 \mod{2}
$$
My question is how did she get from mod6 to mod2, is there an actual rule for this or is it a mistake?

Comment: Your professor only made a comment about the value in $\mod{2}$, nothing about $\mod{6}$. So it was only a hint, not a full solution. Also, it should be pretty clear that $2^{\text{anything (except 0)}} \equiv 0 \mod{2}$.

Comment: This was used as a part of the solution: https://i.imgur.com/iCTTYm3_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Comment: Okay so I interpret all this like so: In order to calculate $2^{2012}~\mod{6}$, your professor gave the following two hints:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
2^{2012}\equiv 0 \mod{2} \\
2^{2012}\equiv 1 \mod{3}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now you're supposed to combine these informations in order to get the result in $\mod{6}$. Here is an example of a similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612036/how-to-combine-congruences

Comment: The thing is the same congruence will also hold for the any divisor of modulo. If $M = mn$ and $X \equiv_M Y$ then $X \equiv_m Y$ and $X \equiv_n Y$. This is an intuitive theorem that is pretty trivial to prove. It is also essential to the CRT. Your professor's reply depends on this.

Comment: Okay, that I now understand. Just one more thing - when should you separate it? Always when it's not prime?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is prime or not. Only divisors of $p$ are $1, p$. Then the congruence $X \equiv_p Y$ means $X \equiv_1 Y$. So $1 | X - Y$. One divides every number. Factors of our modulo not matters. You can separate (or *reduce*) the congruence to any of them.

Comment: $X=2^{2012} \mod{6}$ means $X=2^{2012} +6k$ and even + even = even.

Answer (score 1):

By CRT: $\ \ x\equiv 2^{\large 2N}\!\pmod{\!6}\iff \begin{align} &x\equiv 2^{\large 2N}\!\equiv 0\!\! \pmod{\!2}\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \  N > 0\ \ ({\rm here}\ 2N = 2012)\\ &x\equiv \color{#c00}2^{\large\color{#c00} 2N}\!\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!3}\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ (\color{#c00}{2^{\large 2}})^N\equiv \color{#c00}1^N\!\equiv 1 \end{align}\ \ $

But $\,x\equiv 1\pmod{\!3}$ is redundant (same as first congruence in system) leaving only $\,x\equiv 0\pmod{\!2}$